# mysql_connect() access denied

Tags: php, mysql, connection

I'm having a problem with this connection. I've also done "grant all" for this user

```
Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Access denied for user 'kristian'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in connection.php on line 8
Failed to connect to MySQL: Access denied for user 'kristian'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

the connection.php

```
<?php

define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_NAME', 'email');
define('DB_USER', 'kristian');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'password');

$con=mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
$db=mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$con) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());

?>
```

Comment: As an aside, why are you using mysql? It's been deprecated. Use [mysqli](http://sg3.php.net/mysqli) instead.

Comment: I used mysqli and it still gave me an error

Comment: Or use pdo it is better

Comment: you password is incorrect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, use mysqli instead of mysql. Also try running

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON email.* TO kristian@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

to make sure you have the correct access rights.

Comment: Try running `mysql -h localhost -u kristian -p` and see if you can connect to mysql via the command line. If so, then the problem is with php, else it is with the mysql configuration. I am pretty sure it is the former but you need to check it out.

Comment: I connected. But I don't think it's the problem with the PHP cos I've used that connection string to my other projects and it worked fine. Is it okay to use localhost if the project is uploaded into the webhost?

Comment: It depends on the provider. Some allow using localhost but most of them provide you with the full url location of the mysql server. However, since you receive an error message that access is denied you are connecting to some mysql server.